# Pass IP of kube-dns as env to container

Tags: kubernetes, kube-dns

Is there a way to pass the kube-dns server IP to the container so that services inside the container can resolve the names properly?

I am trying to run nginx and it needs a `resolver` directive to be specified to resolve names against a DNS server.

I do not want to use public DNS servers; only the one provided by kube-dns.

Also, I need a dynamic way to pass the IP as the DNS server IP can change across various cloud platforms or bare-metal configurations. So, I cannot use a hardcoded `10.0.0.10` IP.

Comment: If you omit the resolver, it will use the docker container's DNS resolver, which is set at the cluster level. Just don't set it?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, it seems quite simple.
A few points I had missed.

1. `kube-dns` runs as a Kubernetes Service in the `kube-system` namespace.
2. The DNS name for the service is `kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local`
3. We can pass this to the container using `env`.

EDIT:

It seems I was looking at the wrong place. It indeed uses the local resolver resolve. The problem is I hit a 'feature' in NGINX which caches the lookups for 300 secs and causes name resolution failure, and I was investigating k8s.

Comment: As a side note, you can drop the `svc.cluster.local` altogether. If your kubelet is aware of the cluster domain it will add it as a `search` entry in the resolv.conf of every pod it starts.